# prove the determinant identities

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, laplace-expansion

Let $M$ be an $n \times n$ matrix, $N = \{1, \dots , n \}$ and $V \subseteq N$. Let $M^{(V)}$ denote the submatrix $(m_{i,j})$ of $M$ with $i,j \in V$. Prove that

1. $$\det(Y-\iota I_n)^{(U)}=\sum_{W\subseteq U} (-\iota)^{card(W)} \det(Y^{(U-W)})$$ where $U \subseteq \{1, \dots , n\}$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion
2. If $Y$ is a regular(invertible) ($n \times n$)-matrix over some arbitrary field $K$ and  $U \subseteq \{1, \dots , n\}$ and $\bar U=\{1, \dots , n\}-U.$ then

$$\det(Y^{(U)})=\det(Y^{-1})^{(\bar U)} \det(Y)$$
I don't know how to prove these statements, please help!

Comment: Try to visualize the  problem in $\mathbb R^3$ in order to understand the sens of it. The determinant is an alternating multilinear map so it will be useful for you to know some key definitions on this topic. Your problem is one of multilinear algebra.

Comment: @Piquito Thanks for the hint, can you suggest some references on multilinear algebra?

Comment: only in French, I am sorry. In Google you can find a lot I guess.

Comment: @Piquito Okay Thanks!

Comment: For part 2: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87877/jacobis-equality-between-complementary-minors-of-inverse-matrices

Comment: For part 1: e.g., Proposition 6.4.29 in [my *An Introduction to Algebraic
Combinatorics* as of October 14, 2021](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/21s/lecs.pdf). (Set $x = -\iota$.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg, Thanks for these useful references.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I have one doubt related to part 1; in proposition 6.4.29 if set $x=-\iota$ then it will equals to $det(A-\iota I_n)$  not $det (A-\iota I_n)^{(U)}$ ??

Comment: Oh, right -- you also need to apply the proposition to $A^{(U)}$ instead of $A$.